# Parse and modify protobuf files

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc

Suppose I have the following `proto` file.

```
syntax = "proto3";
package your.service.v1;

import "google/api/annotations.proto";

message FirstMessage {
  string value = 1;
}
message SecondMessage {
  string value = 1;
}

service YourService {
  rpc Echo1(FirstMessage) returns (FirstMessage) {}
  rpc Echo2(SecondMessage) returns (SecondMessage) {
    option (my_option) = {
      expose_for_web: true
    };
  }
}
```

I want to iterate over rpcs of my service and if the rpc contains an option (in this case Echo2 method) keep it and otherwise remove it.
The reason I want to do this is that I have an large project with lots of protos. I want to compile it to a lightweight Typescript code. I want to only compile the rpcs which have an specific annotation.
Is there any tool or library which I could use to modify and rewrite proto files?

Comment: I've no real answer I'm afraid. That sounds like you wanting to modify the generated code. I think that you're going to have to create a bunch of scripts involving tools like `sed` or other text search / manipulation commands to automate the editing of the code. Could be tricky to maintain; if a new version of the protobuf code generator changes the style of the generated code, you might have to amend such scripts.

Comment: This would be easy in C++ or other compiled languages with options for static linking; the linker won't include library object code that isn't referenced by the compiled code. Typescript is sort of compiled; what does that do with un-referenced classes?

Comment: I don't want to manipulate generated code. I want to manipulate proto files and use and generate code from manipulated ones.